# os.path.exists() say False

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to make a code that downloads a file if it doesn't exist

```
import requests
from os.path import exists
def downloadfile(url):
    if exists('file.txt')==False:
        local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
            r.raise_for_status()
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                    f.write(chunk)
        return

downloadfile('https://url.to/file.txt')
```

my folder:

```
testfolder
    test.py
    file.txt
    ...
```

in idle

```
from os.path import exists
exists('file.txt') # True
```

in test.py, exists() say False
how fix it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! Python looks for the file `file.txt` in the *current folder*, not the folder the script is located. Are you sure that 1) the file exists and 2) `test.py` is running in the directory `testfolder`?

Comment: I bet this is just a problem with you not understanding what *relative* pathnames mean.  When you call `exists('file.txt')`, it is testing to see if a file called "file.txt" exists *in the current directory*.  A common reason for it to fail is that the current directory is not where you expect it to be.  So ... basically ... the `exists` call is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: To find out what the current directory is for the script your are running:  `print(os.cwd())`.   Note that your IDE (I assume that is what you meant by "idle") may *change* the current working directory to be different to what your command shell says it is.  On Linux / MacOS, every process has its own notion of the current directory.  Changing it in one process doesn't change it for other processes.

Answer (score 0):

If it reads false, it's probably looking in the wrong place. Use the following to see where the code is looking in (file directory):

```py
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

Then you can either put the file you're looking for in that directory or change the code to the file directory which the file is currently in.